# How can you turn a String representation of a class into a bona fide Object?

Tags: java, string, object

I'm writing a program that needs to have Command Objects. A Command contains a String for its name, and an AbstractAction that represents what the Command actually does. Furthermore, a Command has a method, init(), used higher up in the program's hierarchy that instantiates variables for the Command's use (to provide access to the GUI, network, and so on), and a method, execute(), that executes the AbstractAction on a special Thread. Here is an example of creating and using a Command:

```
Command c = new Command("Test", 
new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
});
```

At this point, calling "c.execute();" will print out "Hello world!", as expected.

My goal is to have a text file with pairs of values, which can be parsed to generate a String name and an AbstractAction action. Once that has been done, another class will go through the found names and actions, create Command Objects for each one, and add them to the list of commands in the program, where they can then be used as normal.

Right now, my problem is that I read in a String that represents the body of the private AbstractAction above- but there isn't an easy way to actually convert the String into an actual AbstractAction Object.

One potential idea was creating a temporary java file with the AbstractAction String representation, compiling it, creating a new AbstractAction from it, and then get that reference using reflection, but that seems like overkill. Another was to directly modify the source of the file that parses through the file, so that it would have the code of the AbstractAction written out, but again, this is a bit crazy.

I've tried a few other implementations, including forcing the user to create a subclass of Command, putting their source into a special program folder, and then creating the Commands on initialisation, but this ended up being a lot of work for the user (lots of redundant code).

Please let me know if there's a better way to implement what I want to do- or if there's an easier way to turn the String of the source into an inner Object as above.

Edit 1:
Here is an example of what the text file would look like:

```
//Anything outside of quotes is a comment
"Foo", "System.out.println("Hello world!");"
"Bar", "network.sendOverAFile(new File("test.txt"));"
```

From here, the parser (on startup) would read through the file and extract "Foo" as a String name, and "System ... ;" as a String action. I need to turn action into the code in the body of the AbstractAction, as seen above when creating the Command.
The same would be done for Bar; Bar uses one of the variables passed by init().

As for the subclass implementation I tried, the user would have to create their own subclass of Command, and put it into a source folder. A subclass would look something like this:

```
public class TestCommand extends Command {
    public TestCommand() {
        super("Test", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
                System.out.println("Hello!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This would then be put into a source directory, among every other subclassed Command, and compiled. The parser would go through the compiled code segments, and add the relevant information to an array. Every time a Command would normally be executed, the parser scans through the list of all names, and if there is a match, execute the relevant AbstractAction. This works, but involves a ton of references to external classes (which will probably slow down the program with dozens of commands), and is two or three times as much work for the users making the plugin. As a result, I felt it would be much easier to use the text file technique above, but I don't know how to turn a String representation of the code into the code itself; Ergo my initial question.

Comment: Use a scripting language for implementations?

Comment: It really sounds like you're after a plug-in architecture. i.e. having your users subclass command. It shouldn't have lots of redundant code. So perhaps post what you did.

Comment: It would help if you included in your question one or more examples of the parseable Strings that you expect to be in this text file.

Comment: Added an edit reflecting the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case of overengineering.  Do you really need this much flexibility at runtime, or do you simply have a lot of commands and you want an easy way to refer to them in a file?

If it's the latter, your text file doesn't need to contain the code;  it just needs to contain symbolic identifiers corresponding to that code.  Those identifiers should exist in your code as enum constants:

```
public enum Command { FOO, BAR }
```

You should create all of your actions in code, and place those actions in a Map using the enum constants as keys.  Your file can then refer to the actions by those enum constants:

```
public List<Action> parseActions(Path file)
throws IOException {
    List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader reader =
            Files.newBufferedReader(file, Charset.defaultCharset())) {

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Command command = Command.valueOf(line);
            Action action = getAction(command);
            actions.add(action);
        }
    }

    return actions;
}

private Map<Command, Action> allActions;

private Action getAction(Command command) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(command, "Command cannot be null");

    if (allActions == null) {
        allActions = new EnumMap<>(Command.class);
        allActions.put(Command.FOO, new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello world!");
            }
        };
        allActions.put(Command.BAR, new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                network.sendOverAFile(new File("test.txt"));
            }
        };

        // Safety check
        if (!allActions.keySet().containsAll(
                EnumSet.allOf(Command.class))) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Not every Command constant has an associated Action");
        }
    }

    return allActions.get(command);
}
```

To conform to the above, your text file would simply contain:

```
FOO
BAR
```

If you really and truly need fully dynamic code that can be read from a text file, bear in mind that it is a tremendous security hole.  In fact, it is the very definition of code injection:  anyone can place arbitrary code (including things like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rd /s/q C:\\Windows\\System32")` or `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf ~")`) in a file and your program will gladly run it.

If you're still sure that you want to do it, you'd probably want to use the JavaScript engine that comes with every Java runtime:

```
public List<Action> parseActions(Path file)
throws IOException {
    List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<>();

    final ScriptEngine engine =
        new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    Bindings bindings = engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
    bindings.put("network", myNetwork);

    try (BufferedReader reader =
            Files.newBufferedReader(file, Charset.defaultCharset())) {

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] nameAndCode = line.split("\\s+", 2);
            String name = nameAndCode[0];
            final String code = nameAndCode[1];

            Action action = new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    engine.eval(code);
                }
            };
            actions.add(action);
        }
    }

    return actions;
}
```

Each line in your file would contain a command name followed by JavaScript code.  So it might look like this:

```
Foo importClass(java.lang.System); System.out.println('Hello world!');
Bar importClass(java.io.File); network.sendOverAFile(new File('test.txt'));
```

Another major disadvantage of doing this, in my opinion, is that the code won't benefit from compiler checks, and you certainly can't set breakpoints in that code from a debugger.  All in all, it will be a considerable headache to debug and maintain.